# Bootstrap 4 circular tabs navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make circular tabs menu using bootstrap 4. I have tried below code using buttons and displaying inline.

I have attached the expected out image below.So first button will be active by default. Only the active button background should have color. Remaining all should be in grey colour. Can any one let me know how to achieve that
[image: Expected this kind.]

Here is the code

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

.xyz {
  background-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-sm {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-circle.btn-md {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>



<body class="xyz">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm">Blue</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-sm">Gray</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm">Green</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm">Red</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-sm">Yellow</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-circle btn-sm">White</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-sm">Black</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some Javascript for this:

- turn all buttons to gray on the first click i.e. add 'blank' class
- turn the button that was clicked to blue i.e. add 'active' class
- you had all types of classes to start off with, which is why !important is needed to force our color through... but for your requirement, you don't need all these colored classes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn").click(function() {

    $(".btn").each(function() {
      ($(this).hasClass('blank')) ? null: $(this).addClass('blank');
      ($(this).hasClass('active')) ? $(this).removeClass('active'): null;
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

.xyz {
  background-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-sm {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-circle.btn-md {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn.btn-sm.btn-circle.blank {
  background: lightgray;
  border-color: lightgray;
}

.btn.btn-sm.btn-circle.active {
  background-color: blue !important;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="xyz">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm">Blue</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-sm">Gray</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm">Green</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm">Red</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-sm">Yellow</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-circle btn-sm">White</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-sm">Black</button>
</div>
```